# Pandas: Transpose columns (b,c,d) grouped by column a as index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
data = pd.DataFrame({'file':['file1','file1','file1','file2','file2','file2' ], 'x': [1,2,3,1,2,4], 'y': [10,20,30,10, 20, 40], 'norm_y': [2,4,6,2,4,8]})

print (data)

out: 
    file  x   y  norm_y
0  file1  1  10       2
1  file1  2  20       4
2  file1  3  30       6
3  file2  1  10       2
4  file2  2  20       4
5  file2  4  40       8
```

I want to print it so that:

- file is the main index
- x,y,z are the sub index

so that it looks like this:

```py
    file          
0         x     1  2  3
1  file1  y     10 20 30
2         ynorm 2  4  6
3         x     1  2  4
4  file2  y     10 20 40
5         ynorm 2  4  8
```

I think the answer is going to be something like:

- set row index: data.set_index(['file'])
- transpose the x,y,ynorm columns

Comment: There are a lot of correct responses below, itd be nice to see runtimes on all them if someone wants to take a stab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is at its core a `pivot` problem, but not really a straightforward one.

---

```
df.assign(
  key=df.groupby('file').cumcount()).set_index(['file', 'key']).stack().unstack('key')
```

```
key            0   1   2
file
file1 x        1   2   3
      y       10  20  30
      norm_y   2   4   6
file2 x        1   2   4
      y       10  20  40
      norm_y   2   4   8
```

Answer (score 3):

you just need a little imagination:

```
data.set_index('file').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.T)
```

Output:

```
file          file2  file2  file2
file                             
file1 x           1      2      3
      y          10     20     30
      norm_y      2      4      6
file2 x           1      2      4
      y          10     20     40
      norm_y      2      4      8
```

Comment: Upvoted because it seems fastest than the other answers !

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df['col' ] = df.groupby('file').cumcount()+1
df.pivot_table(index='file', columns='col').stack(level=0)
```

Output:

```
col            1   2   3
file                    
file1 norm_y   2   4   6
      x        1   2   3
      y       10  20  30
file2 norm_y   2   4   8
      x        1   2   4
      y       10  20  40
```

Answer (score 1):

Playing with `numpy` reshapes

```
fil, var, val = df.melt('file').values.T

new = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([fil.reshape(-1,3)[:, 0].reshape(-1,1), 
                              var.reshape(-1,3)[:, 0].reshape(-1,1), 
                              val.reshape(-1,3)]))\
        .set_index([0,1])\
        .sort_index()
```

---

```
               2   3   4
0     1                 
file1 norm_y   2   4   6
      x        1   2   3
      y       10  20  30
file2 norm_y   2   4   8
      x        1   2   4
      y       10  20  40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
(
    pd.melt(data, id_vars='file', value_vars=['x', 'y', 'norm_y']) #Unstacks the data
    .groupby(['file', 'variable'])['value'] #restacks with file and variable as index
    .aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x)) #splits out values in to a column
    .apply(pd.Series) #turns them into separate columns
)
```